# NSMutableArray with NSMutableSet error in Xcode 5 that compiles fine in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The following lines compile just fine in Xcode 4:

```
NSMutableArray *midiViewsToRemove = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:[self.noteViewControllers allKeys]];

NSMutableArray *audioViewsToRemove = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:[self.audioNoteViewControllers allKeys]];
```

but Xcode 5 gives me the following error:

> Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableArray *' with an
>   expression of type 'NSMutableSet *'

Help!

Comment: first intilize the array and do what you want you are not initialize the array..

Answer (score 5):

This code is wrong, and only worked previously because methods like `setWithArray:` would return `id` but now return `instancetype` which helps the compiler to type-check.

You cannot assign an `NSMutableSet*` to an `NSMutableArray*`. Some of the methods shared by both classes may have worked previously but this is dangerous and only worked accidentally.

Declare your variables as `NSMutableSet *midiViewsToRemove` and `NSMutableSet *audioViewsToRemove`.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  You don't happen to freelance, do you? I'm looking for some help.